# Initializing final fields from a subclass in Dart

Tags: dart

This does not work:

```
abstract class Par {
  final int x;
}

class Sub extends Par {
  Sub(theX) {
    this.x = theX;
  }
}
```

I get an error in Par saying x must be initialized:

```
warning: The final variable 'x' must be initialized
warning: 'x' cannot be used as a setter, it is final
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Give the superclass a constructor, and make the subclass call `super`:

```
abstract class Par {
  final int x;
  Par (int this.x) {}
}

class Sub extends Par {
  Sub(theX) : super(theX)
}
```

You can make the constructor private like so, because [methods and fields starting with `_` are private in Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#important-concepts):

```
abstract class Par {
  final int x;
  Par._(int this.x) {}
}

class Sub extends Par {
  Sub(theX) : super._(theX)
}
```